# Link pages to custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a **WooCommerce** site which has a custom post type named 'products'.

Each product is associated with 1 or more technologies which I have detailed in a set of pages. There are 8 pages in all, one for each technology. The pages are accessible in a "Technologies" menu on the site.

I want to be able to link products and technologies so that I may call up the linked pages on product pages. I will have a technologies section where I will list the technologies, the key image and excerpt. The thing is, every product uses different technologies.

What I have imaged as a solution is a way to link the pages to the product much like I would link categories. Then on the product page, I can get the attached pages to that product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a very useful plugin called "Advanced Custom Fields"(http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which allows this. With this plugin, you can create Relations between a post and other posts/pages.

[image]

Then in you post, you can call up the related post objects and pull all the information you like from them.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, the answer is available at the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages). If this is not the case, you probably have to formulate your question better.

From that page from the codex, you can pick up a line as simple as this one:

```
   <?php wp_list_pages('post_type=yourcustomtype&title_li='); ?>
```